# How to get data safely from DOM object when multiple threads are accessing same object

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, dom, xml-parsing

I have multiple threads trying to read the same DOM object and runs simultaneously.
But I heard that, DOM is not thread safe and somewhere I read that if we clone the document, that cloned document will be thread safe.
this is what I wanted to try

```
    import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document originalDocument = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));
        Node originalRoot = originalDocument.getDocumentElement();

        Document copiedDocument = db.newDocument();
        Node copiedRoot = copiedDocument.importNode(originalRoot, true);
        copiedDocument.appendChild(copiedRoot);

    }
}
```

Now I will allow my threads to read from copiedDocument, instead of originalDocument.

So, Now Do my code runs in thread safe or not? Could anyone please confirm.

Comment: Similar Question: [Creating a DOM that is thread safe for read operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504571/8097737)